# How to get STM8 unique device ID?

Tags: microcontroller, st, stm8

I'm working with a STM8S003F3P6 microcontroller and I need to know an unique ID for each device I will use. I know that PIC microcontrollers has an unique device ID that can be acessed by the user. My questions is: The STM8 microcontrolers have this information? If it's true, how can I acess this?

Thanks in advance!!!

Comment: Have you like, tried looking at the reference manual?

Comment: It's not shown in the datasheet: http://static6.arrow.com/aropdfconversion/357cbdb1a39d775647c8faca3418b803e476573b/4183811972466497dm0002.pdf

Comment: But you should look in reference manual as well. There should be some 96-bit encoded ID if *my* internet search is correct.

Comment: STM8S103F2 STM8S103F3 STM8S103K3 have this, I don't think STM8S003F3P6 does.

Comment: Thank you @SpehroPefhany. As you said the STM8S1... devices have it, and it's clearly said in the datasheets. My hope was that every device have a intrinsic marking number that I can acess.

Comment: Programmer software commonly has a serialize feature to create this as you go.

Answer (score 1):

For all who need this information: The STM8S0... series has an unique ID number as the STM8S1... series. It's located in the same address that in STM8S1... but it's only not said in datasheet.

Thank you for who help!!!

Comment: Interesting.   Many of ST's ARM parts also turn out to have extra memory or features that officially aren't in that particularly version but are documented for a related one.  However one thing to be wary of is that unofficial features might not fully work.  For example, an unofficial unique ID might not be fully unique.

Answer (score 0):

```
#define SERIAL_NUM_ADDR 0x4926

const uint8_t * const serial= (uint8_t *)SERIAL_NUM_ADDR;
```

serial - you can use as a normal array ( pointer ) with 12 bytes length