# How to obtain the unique id of STM microcontroller?

Tags: stm32, cmsis

I need to know how to obtain the STM32f107 microcontroller unique ID. I have read [this page](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/390004/how-to-get-stm8-unique-device-id) but it doesn't cover how to find the address of unique ID of different STM MCU.

Comment: get the datasheet and programming reference guide – there's a special ID register that you can simply read like any other address.

Comment: [Reference Manual](https://www.st.com/resource/en/reference_manual/cd00171190-stm32f101xx-stm32f102xx-stm32f103xx-stm32f105xx-and-stm32f107xx-advanced-armbased-32bit-mcus-stmicroelectronics.pdf), page 1075, section 30.2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just read the memory addresses where it is stored. You can read what memory addresses contain the ID from the manual, but STM32 headers have most likely defined the ID addresses for you so you just need to figure out by which register name you can read it.